# Hacking a 2 gang intermediate switch

Tags: multiway-switch

I have a requirement for a 2-gang intermediate light switch (specifically, only one of the gangs needs to be intermediate - the other can be 1 or 2 way).

There seems to be very few of these available, and those that are available are either extortionately expensive or look pretty poor. Also, almost all of the house is fitted with the same switch at the moment, so I really want to try and keep the consistency throughout the house.

The manufacturer I have been using for all my switches/sockets (MK) do make a 1-gang intermediate switch.

What I intend to try is;

- purchase the 1-gang intermediate switch and a 2-gang 2-way switch
- remove the module from the intermediate switch and from one of the gangs on the 2-gang switch
- install the intermediate module on one of the gangs on the 2-gang switch

I know that technically this will work - my question is has anyone managed to do it without destroying the switch?

Comment: What is an "intermediate" switch?

Comment: Sometimes known as 3-way switch

Comment: @JimStewart -- UK nomenclature uses "3-way" or "intermediate" for what North Americans call a 4-way switch